# Eclipse project and maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I have the project in eclipse with static folder (lib). This folder contains a lot of libraries, also build process of this project based on the maven. Can I automate import(using eclipse maven plugin) all libraries for lib folder to the maven dependencies or I should do it manually?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I automate import (using eclipse maven plugin) all libraries for lib folder to the maven dependencies or I should do it manually?

To strictly answer your question, there is no automated tool, although you could maybe script something in the spirit of [Finding the right version of the right JAR in a maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063215/finding-the-right-version-of-the-right-jar-in-a-maven-repository).

And see [Maven, how to add additional libs not available in repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479046/maven-how-to-add-additional-libs-not-available-in-repo) for the various possibilities to deal with your JARs.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this solutions :), and question was about avto import, ok I'll start to add libraries manualy using solutions that you described in post, Thanks.