# Is there a way to automatically generate the gradle dependencies declaration in build.gradle?

Tags: jar, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

This is in the context of converting an existing java project into a gradle project.

Is there a tool or webservice that would help generate the **dependencies** declaration in the build.gradle by pointing to a directory that contain all the dependent jars ?

Comment: No, jars contain no information about their Maven coordinates.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver. I wish we had a good naming convention to derive the Maven coordinates from the JAR. Your thoughts?

Comment: Your jars are *probably* named in the form [name]-[version].jar, so missing any group info. In which case, you may be able to get away with a search, but will probably not be 100% reliable.  So you could check MD5s, but this is beginning to get pretty complex!

Comment: Agree that it would be pretty complex to reliably develop a tool to get the maven coordinates from JAR name. I wish the entire developer community decides on a convention now that Maven coordinates seem to be the defacto standard for lot of build tools. (Maven, Gradle etc..) :)

Comment: This question may be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063215/finding-the-right-version-of-the-right-jar-in-a-maven-repository

Comment: Thanks for the link @OliverCharlesworth. It is very pertinent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comments to @Opal 's answer, I said that I was working on a quick and dirty groovy script to achieve this. I forgot to attach the script after that. Apologies for the same.

Here's my quick and dirty script. Does solve the purpose partially. 
***Hoping that someone can improve on it.***

---

```html
#! /usr/bin/env groovy

@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.2' )

import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC


//def artifactid = "activation"
//def version = "1.1"
//def packaging = "jar"
//
//def mavenCentralRepository = new RESTClient( "http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=a:%22${artifactid}%22%20AND%20v:%22${version}%22%20AND%20p:%22${packaging}%22&rows=20&wt=json".toString() )
////basecamp.auth.basic userName, password
//
//def response = mavenCentralRepository.get([:])
//println response.data.response.docs
//
//def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
//def parsedJson = slurper.parseText(response.data.toString());
//
//println parsedJson.response.docs.id

def inputFile = new File("input.txt");
def fileList = []
fileList = inputFile.readLines().collect {it.toString().substring(it.toString().lastIndexOf('/') + 1)}
def artifactIDvsVersionMap = [:]

fileList.collectEntries(artifactIDvsVersionMap) {
 def versionIndex = it.substring(0,it.indexOf('.')).toString().lastIndexOf('-')
 [it.substring(0,versionIndex),it.substring(versionIndex+1).minus(".jar")]
}

println artifactIDvsVersionMap

new File("output.txt").delete();

def output = new File("output.txt")
def fileWriter = new FileWriter(output, true)
def parsedGradleParameters = null
try {
 parsedGradleParameters = artifactIDvsVersionMap.collect {
  def artifactid = it.key
  def version = it.value
  def packaging = "jar"

  def mavenCentralRepository = new RESTClient( "http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=a:%22${artifactid}%22%20AND%20v:%22${version}%22%20AND%20p:%22${packaging}%22&rows=20&wt=json".toString() )

  def response = mavenCentralRepository.get([:])
  println response.data.response.docs.id

  def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
  def parsedJson = slurper.parseText(response.data.toString());
  def dependency = parsedJson.response.docs.id
  fileWriter.write("compile '${dependency}'")
  fileWriter.write('\n')
  sleep (new Random().nextInt(20));
  return parsedJson.response.docs.id
 }
} finally {
 fileWriter.close()
}

println parsedGradleParameters
```

*Groovy pros - Pardon if the code is not not clean. :)*

Comment: The sleep in the code is to ensure that the maven repo site doesn't consider this a DDOS.

Answer (score 2):

In general there no such tool but if all the jars all structured (I mean paths: `com/google/guava/guava` and so on) it should be easy to write such script on your own.

Mind that it can also be done by importing the whole folder in the following way:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Opal. I did not want to use the flatDir since I did not want to add the jars to the version control. I am writing a quick an need dirty groovy script that acts as a rest client for the Maven Central repository search. Will post it when done.  By the way, your profile pic is very lively and happy :-)

Comment: You're welcome, thank You very much :) I realize that this isn't exactly what You're looking for but nevertheless added it as a possible solution. Indeed, adding jars to VCS isn't good idea. It's quite funny - in java world we don't that but iOS developers still discuss it ;] Let me know if you have any further problems.

Comment: Please check my answer above @Opal. Added the groovy script.